# Jquery, get the mousemove event with a div overlaping

Tags: jquery, mousemove, overlapping

please help me.

I need to be able to draw a rectangle over images that are in a div with scroller.

With IE 9 or firefox when the mouse hit the rectangle area
stop sending the mousemove event to the image.

How can i make the mousemove event work, even if a div is over the image?

```
$("#AnImage")
.mousedown(function(event)
{
//Set the start point and create the new div as a marker. Start the creating process.
})
.mousemove(function(event)
{
//Moves according to the initial point, set the with and height of the marker
})
.mouseup(function(event){
//Stop the creating process. A new Rectangle is over the image.
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `mosemove` is just a typo here? It's `mousemove` in your real code?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: Yes is MouseMove.. the Jquery event. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `pointer-events` CSS property - if you have no items inside the `<div>` that you want to draw over the image.

```
#AnImage {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

More info on the property: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events), [here](http://www.webkit.org/specs/PointerEventsProperty.html), and [here](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events).

Comment: WOW!!.. i didn't knew this css property! Its amazing!!... that solve my problem!!... but i want to see why firefox stop sending the mousemove events, even if they are behind.